# Add shadow on graph

Tags: d3.js

I am using D3 js to create stacked area chart. Here is the link for my code:

https://jsfiddle.net/6um7xans/

My JS:

```
var sum_height_2009=0;
var sum_height_2013=0;
var count;
//console.log(trend_obj);
var marginTop = 10;
var marginBottom = 20;
var marginRight = 15;
var marginLeft = 30;
var height = 480 - marginTop - marginBottom;
var width = 627 - marginLeft - marginRight;

var svgSelection = d3.select('#chart1')
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + marginLeft + marginRight)
    .attr("height", height + marginTop + marginBottom);

var baseGroup = svgSelection
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate("+marginLeft+","+marginTop+")");


var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height,0])
    .domain([0,100]);   


var xScale = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width])

//assign colores for segments
var colorScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["url(#gradient)", "url(#gradient2)", "url(#gradient3)", "url(#gradient4)","url(#gradient5)","url(#gradient6)","url(#gradient7)","url(#gradient8)","url(#gradient9)","url(#gradient10)"]);

var hoverLabel = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range("age1", "age2", "age3", "age4","age5");


var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(yScale)    
    .ticks(10)
    .tickFormat(function(d){if(d==100){return "$"+(d) ;}else{return "$"+(d)}})
    .orient("left");

var format = d3.time.format("%Y");
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)      


var dataset = [
    { year: "2009", age1: 10, age2: 0, age3: 12, age4: 17, age5: 16, age6: 11, age7: 10, age8: 12, age9: 17, age10: 15},
    { year: "2010", age1: 12, age2: 12, age3: 10, age4: 18, age5: 20, age6: 12, age7: 12, age8: 10, age9: 21, age10: 14},
    { year: "2011", age1: 14, age2: 16, age3: 12, age4: 20, age5: 20, age6: 14, age7: 12, age8: 10, age9: 21, age10: 12},
    { year: "2012", age1: 16, age2: 18, age3: 15, age4: 20, age5: 20, age6: 16, age7: 14, age8: 15, age9: 21, age10: 11},
    { year: "2013", age1: 18, age2: 20, age3: 18, age4: 22, age5: 20, age6: 18, age7: 12, age8: 12, age9: 21, age10: 20}

];

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y");
dataset.forEach(function(d) {    
    d.year = d.year;
}); 

// each key (age), uses a map to create all the objects for that age
// i in the anonymous function passed to map is the index of the dataset array, so can be used as the ID
var newDataset = ["age1", "age2", "age3", "age4","age5"].map(function(n){
    return dataset.map(function(d, i){            
           return { x: d.year, y: d[n], y0: 0 };
       });
});

d3.layout.stack()(newDataset);
xScale.domain(d3.extent(dataset, function(d) {  
   return d.year 
}))

var x_axis_height = height+1;
baseGroup.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(-1," + x_axis_height + ")")
      .style("z-index", 9999)
      .call(xAxis);              

baseGroup.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(-1,1)")
      .style("z-index", 9999)
      .call(yAxis);

var area = d3.svg.area()
    .x(function(d) { return xScale(d.x); })
    .y0(function(d) { return yScale(d.y0); })
    .y1(function(d) { return yScale(d.y + d.y0); });

var ageGroup = baseGroup.selectAll(".valgroup")
    .data(newDataset)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "valgroup")
    .style("border-right", "2px solid gray")
    .style("z-index", -1)
    .style("fill", function(d, i) { return colorScale(i); })
    .attr("class", function(d, i) { return hoverLabel(i); });


ageGroup.append("path") 
    .style("shape-rendering", "auto")    
    .attr("d", function(d) { return area(d); })
    .attr("class", function(d, i) { return hoverLabel(i); })    

  //code to display text in front of graph layers 
    svg=d3.select('svg');  
    function getMyCentroid(element) {
    var bbox = element.getBBox();    
    return [bbox.x + bbox.width / 2, bbox.y + bbox.height / 1.5];
  }
    d3.selectAll("path")[0].forEach(function(d,i) {

    var centroid = getMyCentroid(d);        
        count=i;             
  })





/* gradient colors */
    //gradient 
    svg=d3.select('svg');    
    var gradient = svg.append("defs")
    .append("linearGradient")
      .attr("id", "gradient")
      .attr("x1", "0%")
      .attr("y1", "80%")
      .attr("x2", "20%")
      .attr("y2", "22%")
      .attr("spreadMethod", "pad");

    gradient.append("stop")
    .attr("offset", "40%")
    .attr("stop-color", "#699CD4")
    .attr("stop-opacity", 1);

    gradient.append("stop")
    .attr("offset", "100%")
    .attr("stop-color", "#95B9EA")
    .attr("stop-opacity", 1); 


    //gradient2 
    svg=d3.select('svg');    
    var gradient = svg.append("defs")
    .append("linearGradient")
      .attr("id", "gradient2")
      .attr("x1", "0%")
      .attr("y1", "80%")
      .attr("x2", "30%")
      .attr("y2", "22%")
      .attr("spreadMethod", "pad");

    gradient.append("stop")
    .attr("offset", "20%")
    .attr("stop-color", "#D66A64")
    .attr("stop-opacity", 1);

    gradient.append("stop")
    .attr("offset", "100%")
    .attr("stop-color", "#EC9591")
    .attr("stop-opacity", 1); 


    //gradient2 
    svg=d3.select('svg');    
    var gradient = svg.append("defs")
    .append("linearGradient")
      .attr("id", "gradient3")
      .attr("x1", "0%")
      .attr("y1", "80%")
      .attr("x2", "20%")
      .attr("y2", "22%")
      .attr("spreadMethod", "pad");

    gradient.append("stop")
    .attr("offset", "20%")
    .attr("stop-color", "#A9C767")
    .attr("stop-opacity", 1);

    gradient.append("stop")
    .attr("offset", "100%")
    .attr("stop-color", "#C6E195")
    .attr("stop-opacity", 1); 


    //gradient2 
    svg=d3.select('svg');    
    var gradient = svg.append("defs")
    .append("linearGradient")
      .attr("id", "gradient4")
      .attr("x1", "0%")
      .attr("y1", "80%")
      .attr("x2", "30%")
      .attr("y2", "22%")
      .attr("spreadMethod", "pad");

    gradient.append("stop")
    .attr("offset", "20%")
    .attr("stop-color", "#8B6EAE")
    .attr("stop-opacity", 1);

    gradient.append("stop")
    .attr("offset", "100%")
    .attr("stop-color", "#BCAAD6")
    .attr("stop-opacity", 1); 



    //gradient5 
    svg=d3.select('svg');    
    var gradient = svg.append("defs")
    .append("linearGradient")
      .attr("id", "gradient5")
      .attr("x1", "0%")
      .attr("y1", "80%")
      .attr("x2", "30%")
      .attr("y2", "22%")
      .attr("spreadMethod", "pad");

    gradient.append("stop")
    .attr("offset", "20%")
    .attr("stop-color", "#43B4CF")
    .attr("stop-opacity", 1);

    gradient.append("stop")
    .attr("offset", "100%")
    .attr("stop-color", "#93DBF3")
    .attr("stop-opacity", 1);
```

When I try to add shadow to the right side, it adds to the whole graph. Is there a way to make it look like:

[image]

How to add shadow only to the right side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution: create another set of paths, fill them with `lightgray`, and translate them a little bit right/down:

```
var shadow = baseGroup.selectAll(".shadow")
    .data(newDataset)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .append("path")
    .style("fill", "lightgray")
    .attr("d", function(d) {
        return area(d);
    })
    .attr("transform", "translate(6,3)");
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var sum_height_2009=0;
var sum_height_2013=0;
var count;
//console.log(trend_obj);
var marginTop = 10;
var marginBottom = 20;
var marginRight = 15;
var marginLeft = 30;
var height = 480 - marginTop - marginBottom;
var width = 627 - marginLeft - marginRight;

var svgSelection = d3.select('#chart1')
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + marginLeft + marginRight)
    .attr("height", height + marginTop + marginBottom);

var baseGroup = svgSelection
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate("+marginLeft+","+marginTop+")");


var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height,0])
    .domain([0,100]);   


var xScale = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width])
    
//assign colores for segments
var colorScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["url(#gradient)", "url(#gradient2)", "url(#gradient3)", "url(#gradient4)","url(#gradient5)","url(#gradient6)","url(#gradient7)","url(#gradient8)","url(#gradient9)","url(#gradient10)"]);

var hoverLabel = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range("age1", "age2", "age3", "age4","age5");


var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(yScale)    
    .ticks(10)
    .tickFormat(function(d){if(d==100){return "$"+(d) ;}else{return "$"+(d)}})
    .orient("left");

var format = d3.time.format("%Y");
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)      
    
     
var dataset = [
    { year: "2009", age1: 10, age2: 0, age3: 12, age4: 17, age5: 16, age6: 11, age7: 10, age8: 12, age9: 17, age10: 15},
    { year: "2010", age1: 12, age2: 12, age3: 10, age4: 18, age5: 20, age6: 12, age7: 12, age8: 10, age9: 21, age10: 14},
    { year: "2011", age1: 14, age2: 16, age3: 12, age4: 20, age5: 20, age6: 14, age7: 12, age8: 10, age9: 21, age10: 12},
    { year: "2012", age1: 16, age2: 18, age3: 15, age4: 20, age5: 20, age6: 16, age7: 14, age8: 15, age9: 21, age10: 11},
    { year: "2013", age1: 18, age2: 20, age3: 18, age4: 22, age5: 20, age6: 18, age7: 12, age8: 12, age9: 21, age10: 20}
    
];

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y");
dataset.forEach(function(d) {    
    d.year = d.year;
}); 

// each key (age), uses a map to create all the objects for that age
// i in the anonymous function passed to map is the index of the dataset array, so can be used as the ID
var newDataset = ["age1", "age2", "age3", "age4","age5"].map(function(n){
    return dataset.map(function(d, i){            
           return { x: d.year, y: d[n], y0: 0 };
       });
});

d3.layout.stack()(newDataset);
xScale.domain(d3.extent(dataset, function(d) {  
   return d.year 
}))

var x_axis_height = height+1;

      
var area = d3.svg.area()
    .x(function(d) { return xScale(d.x); })
    .y0(function(d) { return yScale(d.y0); })
    .y1(function(d) { return yScale(d.y + d.y0); });
  
var shadow = baseGroup.selectAll(".shadow")
    .data(newDataset)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
  .append("path") 
    .style("fill", "lightgray")    
    .attr("d", function(d) { return area(d); })
  .attr("transform", "translate(6,3)");

var ageGroup = baseGroup.selectAll(".valgroup")
    .data(newDataset)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "valgroup")
    .style("border-right", "2px solid gray")
    .style("z-index", -1)
    .style("fill", function(d, i) { return colorScale(i); })
    .attr("class", function(d, i) { return hoverLabel(i); });
  
    

ageGroup.append("path") 
    .style("shape-rendering", "auto")    
    .attr("d", function(d) { return area(d); })
    .attr("class", function(d, i) { return hoverLabel(i); }) 
  
  baseGroup.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(-1," + x_axis_height + ")")
      .style("z-index", 9999)
      .call(xAxis);              

baseGroup.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(-1,1)")
      .style("z-index", 9999)
      .call(yAxis);
  

    
  //code to display text in front of graph layers 
    svg=d3.select('svg');  
    function getMyCentroid(element) {
    var bbox = element.getBBox();    
    return [bbox.x + bbox.width / 2, bbox.y + bbox.height / 1.5];
  }
    d3.selectAll("path")[0].forEach(function(d,i) {
    
    var centroid = getMyCentroid(d);        
        count=i;             
  })

  
  

            
/* gradient colors */
    //gradient 
    svg=d3.select('svg');    
    var gradient = svg.append("defs")
    .append("linearGradient")
      .attr("id", "gradient")
      .attr("x1", "0%")
      .attr("y1", "80%")
      .attr("x2", "20%")
      .attr("y2", "22%")
      .attr("spreadMethod", "pad");
    
    gradient.append("stop")
    .attr("offset", "40%")
    .attr("stop-color", "#699CD4")
    .attr("stop-opacity", 1);
    
    gradient.append("stop")
    .attr("offset", "100%")
    .attr("stop-color", "#95B9EA")
    .attr("stop-opacity", 1); 
    
    
    //gradient2 
    svg=d3.select('svg');    
    var gradient = svg.append("defs")
    .append("linearGradient")
      .attr("id", "gradient2")
      .attr("x1", "0%")
      .attr("y1", "80%")
      .attr("x2", "30%")
      .attr("y2", "22%")
      .attr("spreadMethod", "pad");
    
    gradient.append("stop")
    .attr("offset", "20%")
    .attr("stop-color", "#D66A64")
    .attr("stop-opacity", 1);
    
    gradient.append("stop")
    .attr("offset", "100%")
    .attr("stop-color", "#EC9591")
    .attr("stop-opacity", 1); 
    
    
    //gradient2 
    svg=d3.select('svg');    
    var gradient = svg.append("defs")
    .append("linearGradient")
      .attr("id", "gradient3")
      .attr("x1", "0%")
      .attr("y1", "80%")
      .attr("x2", "20%")
      .attr("y2", "22%")
      .attr("spreadMethod", "pad");
    
    gradient.append("stop")
    .attr("offset", "20%")
    .attr("stop-color", "#A9C767")
    .attr("stop-opacity", 1);
    
    gradient.append("stop")
    .attr("offset", "100%")
    .attr("stop-color", "#C6E195")
    .attr("stop-opacity", 1); 
    
    
    //gradient2 
    svg=d3.select('svg');    
    var gradient = svg.append("defs")
    .append("linearGradient")
      .attr("id", "gradient4")
      .attr("x1", "0%")
      .attr("y1", "80%")
      .attr("x2", "30%")
      .attr("y2", "22%")
      .attr("spreadMethod", "pad");
    
    gradient.append("stop")
    .attr("offset", "20%")
    .attr("stop-color", "#8B6EAE")
    .attr("stop-opacity", 1);
    
    gradient.append("stop")
    .attr("offset", "100%")
    .attr("stop-color", "#BCAAD6")
    .attr("stop-opacity", 1); 
    
    
    
    //gradient5 
    svg=d3.select('svg');    
    var gradient = svg.append("defs")
    .append("linearGradient")
      .attr("id", "gradient5")
      .attr("x1", "0%")
      .attr("y1", "80%")
      .attr("x2", "30%")
      .attr("y2", "22%")
      .attr("spreadMethod", "pad");
    
    gradient.append("stop")
    .attr("offset", "20%")
    .attr("stop-color", "#43B4CF")
    .attr("stop-opacity", 1);
    
    gradient.append("stop")
    .attr("offset", "100%")
    .attr("stop-color", "#93DBF3")
    .attr("stop-opacity", 1);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 12px;
  color:#9DA0A4;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #5c6067;
  stroke-width:2px; 
  shape-rendering: auto;
}

.browser text {
  text-anchor: end;
} 
#chart1{
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 67px;
}
svg{
    overflow: visible;
}
.cost_in_B{
    position: absolute;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #5c6067;
    left:3%;
    top:0%;
    
}
.year-bottom{
    position: absolute;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #5c6067;
    left:6%;
    bottom:35%;
}
.cagr-head{
        position: absolute;        
        color: black;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 15px;
        left:40%;
        top:0%;    
    }
    .cagr-percent{
        color: #5c6067;
    }
    .segment-div{
        position:absolute;
        left:60%;
        //top:10%;
    }
    .seg-label{
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .seg-rect{
        display:inline-block; 
        height:16px;
        //background:#638EC6;
        width: 30px;                
    }
    
    .seg-rect{
        position:absolute;
        left:60%;
        //top:10%;
    }
    .seg-label{
        position:absolute;
        left:65%; 
        font-family: Helvetica;
        color: #5c6067;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<div id="chart1"></div>
```

Have in mind that, in my solution, if you translate down the shadow paths to much, they will show up under the x axis.

PS: remove all those "z-index" styles. They have no effect in an SVG.